# I need to create a nested complex XML into a dataframe using a Python Script

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have multiple nested xmls with different fields. Can anyone suggest a generalise script or a tutorial to do the above mentioned task

I'm trying to convert nested XML into dataframe using Python script.I saw some solutions using api calling but not able to get those options to explode xml.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a nested XML file into a pandas DataFrame requires parsing the XML and then structuring the data in a way that fits into a DataFrame.

You can use the lxml library to parse the XML and then build a pandas DataFrame from the parsed data.

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

def xml_to_dict(xml_string):
    root = etree.fromstring(xml_string)
    data = {}
    for child in root:
        data[child.tag] = []
        for subchild in child:
            subdata = {}
            for subsubchild in subchild:
                subdata[subsubchild.tag] = subsubchild.text
            data[child.tag].append(subdata)
    return data

def xml_to_dataframe(xml_string):
    data_dict = xml_to_dict(xml_string)
    frames = {}
    for key, values in data_dict.items():
        frames[key] = pd.DataFrame(values)
    return frames

# Sample XML string with nested elements
xml_string = """
<root>
    <users>
        <user>
            <name>John</name>
            <age>28</age>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>Jane</name>
            <age>25</age>
        </user>
    </users>
    <products>
        <product>
            <name>Apple</name>
            <price>1.5</price>
        </product>
        <product>
            <name>Banana</name>
            <price>1.2</price>
        </product>
    </products>
</root>
"""

frames = xml_to_dataframe(xml_string)

# Print the DataFrame for users
print(frames['users'])

# Print the DataFrame for products
print(frames['products'])
```

This code will take the given XML and produce two DataFrames, one for users and one for products. You can adjust the xml_to_dict function to match the specific structure of your XML if it is different from this example.